# Tags that need to be escaped when used as a link sometimes aren't

Tags: support, tags, tag-links

This happens very occasionally, although has happened twice today.

I'll go to http://stackoverflow.com then find a question with the [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) and click it to view that tag's questions. However, the page i'm given shows questions tagged [c](/questions/tagged/c) and the URL has C# instead of C%23 in it.

I'm on chrome (latest version) and like i say it only happens occasionally. If I click back in the browser the urls look to be ok.

Please tell me there some ajax-type url encoding going on or something and I'm not going mad! The only thing I can think of happening is that I'm clicking the [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) too fast, before URLs are sorted out or something.

---

<sup>Alternatively please tell microsoft to change the name of C# to something that doesn't need to be url encoded.</sup>

Comment: Cannot repro. And it is unlikely to be *"some ajax-type url encoding"* since I've grabbed some pages using `wget` and all links come pre-encoded. No client-side jiggery pokery involved.

Comment: Hmm, ok I guess chrome is doing something very weird or I'm going mad! Thanks for taking to time to do some testing.